# All tab elements are active when using uk-tab with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, getuikit

I am using getuikit's tab component ( https://getuikit.com/docs/tab ) in my Vue-App:

Now I see that every tab is active, if I use `v-for` to iterate through an array.

```
 <ul class=" uk-tab-left" uk-tab>
                    <li v-for="test in tests" id="test"><a href="#">{{ test }}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

In my codepen example you can see, that the class `uk-active` is always inserted automatically:

https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/Ydzbez

Is there a possibility to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a empty li element before the loop to make sure the active class will not be added to the others.

Don't forget to add a key to the loop and bind the id.

```html
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div uk-grid>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
                <ul class=" uk-tab-left" data-uk-tab>
                  <li></li>
                    <li v-for="test in tests" :key="test" :id="test">
                      <a href="#">{{ test }}</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div uk-grid>
            <div class="uk-width-1-4@m">
                <ul class=" uk-tab-left" data-uk-tab>
                    <template v-for="test in tests">
                        <li  :key="test" :id="test">
                            <a href="#">{{ test }}</a>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```